# QlikView OCX problems

Tags: delphi, qlikview

I have the "luck" to work with quikview, and I have to control it via the ocx component qlikOCX.
I've imported the the OCX component into my (delphi 2009) IDE, and now I can simply drag an TQlikOCX object to my form and use it.

Unfortunately, when I do something simple like

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  QlikOCX1.DocName := 'c:\qv\mydoc.qvw';
  QlikOCX1.ActiveDocument.ActiveSheet.FitZoomToWindow;
end;
```

Delphi throws an unknown EOLEException.
When I run the compiled programm outside the IDE, it works.
Maybe someone can give me a hint how to debug this, or even knows the TQlikOCX and the issues with it?
Many thank!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after intesive and long contact with qlikTek support it exposed that the qlikOCX object is very buggy (at least in use with delphi). In the meantime there'san release which works well.